# Java Web Services

Tags: java, web-services

Where can I find good Java web services practicals and tutorials (I'm a newbe to JWS so I prefer from the scratch).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [Sun Tutorial](http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/). These are usually very good

Answer (score 4):

I've always read (though I've never followed) the [Sun tutorials](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html). Well written enough for me.

Though, I would suggest to use a framework like [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) or [spring web services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/) to avoid the boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://www.developer.com/services/article.php/3613896) when learning sth. about web services.

But I'm sure now there are newer ones.

Answer (score 0):

I second the vote for Spring web services.  One advantage is that your services can migrate from stack to stack without modification.  If you're already using Spring, it's a great way to go.